# Time difference between two dates in the log files

Tags: bash, shell, datetime

I am trying to get the time difference between two dates as given below in Bash script. However I am not successful

```
head_info: 05-31-2017:04:27:37
tail_info: 05-31-2017:04:30:57
```

the problem is that after Reformation above time and while trying to calculate in seconds due to space, it is ignoring time.

This is my script:

```
fm_head_info=(${head_info:6:4}"-"${head_info:0:2}"-"${head_info:3:2}" \
             "${head_info:11:8})
fm_tail_info=(${tail_info:6:4}"-"${tail_info:0:2}"-"${tail_info:3:2}" \
             "${tail_info:11:8})
```

> ```
> $ fm_head_info
> -bash: 2017-05-31: command not found
> ```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate issue is the inclusion of erroneous `(...)` surrounding your string indexed assignment and your questionable quoting. It looks like you intended:

```
fm_head_info="${head_info:6:4}-${head_info:0:2}-${head_info:3:2} ${head_info:11:8}"
fm_tail_info="${tail_info:6:4}-${tail_info:0:2}-${tail_info:3:2} ${tail_info:11:8}"
```

Your use of string indexes is correct, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

head_info=05-31-2017:04:27:37
tail_info=05-31-2017:04:30:57

fm_head_info="${head_info:6:4}-${head_info:0:2}-${head_info:3:2} ${head_info:11:8}"
fm_tail_info="${tail_info:6:4}-${tail_info:0:2}-${tail_info:3:2} ${tail_info:11:8}"

echo "fm_head_info: $fm_head_info"
echo "fm_tail_info: $fm_tail_info"
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash headinfo.sh
fm_head_info: 2017-05-31 04:27:37
fm_tail_info: 2017-05-31 04:30:57
```

You can then do something similar with the differences in `date -d "$var" +%s` as John shows in his answer to arrive at the time difference. Note, string indexes are limited to bash, while a `sed` solution (absent the *herestring*) would be portable on all POSIX shells.

Answer (score 2):

Let's define your shell variables:

```
$ tail_info=05-31-2017:04:30:57
$ head_info=05-31-2017:04:27:37
```

Now, let's create a function to convert those dates to seconds-since-epoch:

```
$ date2sec() { date -d "$(sed 's|-|/|g; s|:| |' <<<"$*")" +%s; }
```

To find the time difference between those two date in seconds:

```
$ echo $(( $(date2sec "$tail_info") - $(date2sec "$head_info") ))
200
```

As written above, this requires `bash` (or similar advanced shell) and GNU `date`.  In other words, this should work on any standard Linux.  To make this work on OSX, some changes to the `date` command will likely be necessary.

#### How it works

Starting with the innermost command inside the function `date2sec`, we have:

```
sed 's|-|/|g; s|:| |' <<<"$*"
```

In the argumnet to the function, this replaces all `-` with `/` and it replaces the first `:` with a space.  This converts the the dates from the format in your input to one that the GNU `date` function will understand.  For example:

```
$ sed 's|-|/|g; s|:| |' <<<"05-31-2017:04:30:57"
05/31/2017 04:30:57
```

With this form, we can use `date` to find seconds-since-epoch:

```
$ date -d "05/31/2017 04:30:57" +%s
1496230257
```

And, for the head_info:

```
$ date -d "05/31/2017 04:27:37" +%s
1496230057
```

Now that we have that, all that is left is to subtract the times:

```
$ echo $(( 1496230257 - 1496230057 ))
200
```

Comment: I take my hat off to that answer. Very clever use of command substitution within date fed by a *herestring* `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you!

Comment: Thank you John...you nailed it.